# How to Integrate of Python 2.7.4 in Qt 5.0

Tags: application-development, python-2.7, qt5, sip, pyqt

I have Python 2.7.4 installed,Qt 5.0 installed,PyQt 4.10.4.tar.gz and sip 4.15.5.tar.gz.
How can I integrate Python with my Qt?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
```

write a sample program

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        nameLabel = QLabel("Name:")
        self.nameLine = QLineEdit()
        self.submitButton = QPushButton("&Submit")

        buttonLayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(nameLabel)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.nameLine)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.submitButton)

        self.submitButton.clicked.connect(self.submitContact)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        # mainLayout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout1, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello Qt")

    def submitContact(self):
        name = self.nameLine.text()

        if name == "":
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty Field","Please enter a name and address.")
            return
        else:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Success!","Hello \"%s\"!" % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    screen = Form()
    screen.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

save this as sample.py

execute this by

```
$python3 sample.py
```

source : [link](http://www.thehackeruniversity.com/2014/01/23/pyqt5-beginner-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get install python-qt4

Clear, `apt-get` command do not need compiling, and your `pyqt` do not rely on `Qt`.

But, if your python is build by yourself, you have to compile and install `pyqt` by your self.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539860/how-to-build-pyqt5-on-ubuntu) may be helpful!